# C program interesting behaviour

Tags: c, for-loop

I have stumbled upon a piece of code that generates some interesting results while debugging someone else's program.

I have created a small program to illustrate this behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char* word = "foobar"; int i, iterator = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++ && iterator++)
          printf("%c", word[iterator]);
        return 0;
}
```

I know that this is not the right way to print a string. This is for demonstration purpose only.

Here I expected the output to be "foobar", obviously, but instead it is "ffooba". Basically it reads the first character twice, as if the first time `iterator++` is executed nothing happens.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: `i++ && iterator++` -> `i++, iterator++`

Comment: This question may be basic but it's asked perfectly.

Comment: Like I said, I know how to do it correctly, I just wanted to find out why the above code didn't work the way I expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing is `iterator++` actually *isn't* executed the first time. The `++` operator returns the current value of a variable and *then* increments it, so the first time through, `i++` will be equal to `0`. `&&` short-circuits, so `iterator++` is not executed the first time.

To fix this, you could use the comma operator which unconditionally evaluates both, rather than the short-circuiting `&&`.

Comment: it's funny, I did know about that the && operator doesn't evaluate the second part of the expression if the first one if false already, but I didn't expect that to apply since it wasn't placed in the condition section of the loop statement. thank you for the answer. I'll approve it after 10 minutes pass.

Comment: You can read more about short circuit evaluation. There are various rules for &&, || etc.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `i++` is the current value of `i` which is zero on first iteration. This means  `iterator++` is not executed on first iteration due to short circuting (the right-hand side of `&&` is *only* executed if the left-hand side is "true").

To fix you could use the comma operator (as already suggested or) use `++i` which will return the value of `i` after the incremement (though comma operator is more obvious that both must always be evaluated).

Answer (score 3):

You really should learn to use a debugger like e.g. `gdb` and to compile with warnings and debugging info like `gcc -Wall -g` (assuming a Linux system). A recent `gcc` with `-Wall` gives you a warning about *value computed is not used* before the `&&` operation.

The increment part of your `for` loop is strange. It is `i++ && iterator++` (but it should be `i++, iterator++` instead).

When `i` is 0 (on the first iteration), `i++` gives 0 as result, so it is false, so the `iterator++` is not executed.

Comment: I have used visual studio for a long time but I have recently switched to linux and I haven't learned how to use the console debugger yet, but I will look into that.

Comment: The moral of the story is to always pass `-Wall` to `gcc` and to improve your code till no warning is given. You could even pass `-Wall -Wextra -g` to `gcc`.

Comment: @lonut Hulub you can still use Eclipse for graphical debugger in Linux. However, gdb (console debugger) is a valuable skill nevertheless specially when you are working on a platform with no UI.

Comment: AFAIK, Eclipse debugger for C is just a GUI interface to `gdb` (like `ddd` is). So learning `gdb` is still useful.

Answer (score 2):

I am reading K&R about logic operators,let me quote the origin words of book,which can explain your question.
"Expressions connected by && or || are evaluated left to right, and
evaluation stops as soon as the truth or falsehood of the result is known."
Have a good understanding of these,the outputs wont puzzle.